# How could I make a picture increase in size continually?

Tags: jquery

```
<img src="/images/foo.png" id="bar">
```

I'd like to make the image increase in size slowly and steadily once the page has finished loading.

Comment: you probably want to clarify what 'size' means to you (width, height, file size?)

Comment: I can't think of an instance where you would want to increase the file size steadily (how would that even work?). And by not specifying width or height I imply I want to increase both (and probably maintain aspect ratio). I chose my words with care.

Comment: Wasn't ambiguous to me at all (clearly). I also had that thought re: increasing file size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(window).load(function ()
{
    $('#bar').animate({width: 10000}, 100000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/Vekwa/

---

To improve upon [@Dutchie's never-ending growth implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887555/how-could-i-make-a-picture-increase-in-size-continually/5887623#5887623):

```
$(window).load(function ()
{
    var $bar = $('#bar');

    function grow()
    {
        $bar.animate({width: '+=1px'}, 20, grow);
    }

    grow();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/7bAhY/

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Well, maybe not the cat picture, but the effect. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The answer from `Matt Ball` will work, most likely - but will eventually stop. check out my [never-ending growing image](http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/YsVFf/).

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('#bar').css({width: "+=1px", height: "+=1px"});
}, 100);
```

Comment: You should include the code in the your answer... and **why are you passing a string to `setInterval`**. There are so many ways to do this better.

Comment: Well, your comments are also borderline offensive. Thanks to the motivation I received from your kind, nurturing teachings, I've revised the code to be what I consider to be more refined.

Comment: My apologies for the terseness earlier. There are better ways to show someone how to improve their work.